# Combining data from multiple records into a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

My query looks like this:

```
select analyst, issuer, coveragegroup
from analystcoverage
```

There can be multiple analysts for a particular issuer. When this is the case,
I want to concatenate their names in a single record.

I want these two records:

```
John Doe      Walmart      Fixed Income
Bill Jones    Walmart      Fixed Income
```

to be returned as:

```
John Doe; Bill Jones      Walmart      Fixed Income
```

Comment: This is a fairly commonly asked question. Have you tried searching for other similar questions?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use COALESCE. I know how to use it, but I'm not sure how to tell it to only concatenate records with equal values. Here's the code to get you started:

[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)